# PowerShell script failure on remote execution

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

On executing a PowerShell Remote Script I am getting an error like following

```
Invoke-Command : Exception calling "ToXmlString" with "1" argument(s): "The requested operation cannot be completed. Th
e computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation.
```

The exact line of code the execution is breaking is as follows:

```
    $rsa = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
    $key = $rsa.ToXmlString($true)
```

Can anybody help me to resolve out the issue??

Comment: Can anybody come up with any more to do than Jason told in the first answer? It will be very great

Comment: Probably is late but try to execute powershell locally to see if it fails the same. If it fails, try to execute it locally in an elevated powershell prompt...

Comment: Hi cad, thanks for the input, but I need to execute in remote mode itself. This is a script whiich is currently running fine in local execution. Something related remote access issues is this issue I hope

Comment: If it works in local and fails remotely you might then try something.
Assuming that machine A is where powershell script and Machine B where you want to execute into.
Grant administrator privileges in machine B to all MachineA (you can grant to a full machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks just like what the error says, you need to be trusted for delegation.  I found these links on the web.

- [How do I configure accounts so that
  they are trusted for delegation in a
  Windows Server 2003 Enterprise
  Edition environment?](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/tips/jsi-tip-7359-how-do-i-configure-accounts-so-that-they-are-trusted-for-delegation-in-a-windows-server-2003-enterprise-edition-environment-)
- [Kerberos
  authentication and troubleshooting
  delegation issues](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907272)

Comment: Thanks for those links...
I have already done the settings for the corresponding account and the client computer to be delegated.
Even in the client computer setspn is also executed successfully as being discussed in the second link.
Is there any other options more to be done?

Comment: The machines I am working with are installed with **Windows Server 2008 R2**

Comment: I haven't dealt with this myself, so that's all the help I can be.  :(